# Having a problem with pyautogui and some programs

Tags: python, autohotkey, pyautogui

I ran into a problem using pyautogui with one program. I've used it successfully in the past and this had me stumped for a while. The mouse would not click on a button, or anywhere over the running programs window. I searched but could not find a solution. PyDirectInput would not work either.

I considered using Autohotkey as a workaround but it had the same problem.

The Fix:

I found the solution when searching why Autohotkey would not work. It turned out that the program I was trying to control was running in elevated mode and I needed to run my Python program as Administrator in order to interact with it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was to run my program as Administrator when trying to interact with a program running in elevated mode (also running as Administrator).